# Adding an element to a singlechained linked list

Tags: java, list

Okay, the solution is probably very easy but I don't understand it at the moment.

Code:

```
ListElem<T> first;
int size = 0;
public void add(T value) {
  if (value == null)
    return;
  ListElem<T> elem = new ListElem<T>(value);
  elem.next = first;
  first = elem;
  size++;
}
```

How exactly does this add an element at the beginning of a singlechained linked list?
I create a new element with the given value.

What happens in the next 2 lines? I understand the process of inserting a element in a list but I'm not able to relate it to this code.

And what exactly is first? The head?

Answer (score 3):

Before adding the stack looks like this :

> first -> next -> next -> ... -> end;

You create the elem.

Then you said "The next elem of elem is the first elem".

`elem.next = first;` so you have

> elem -> first;

Finally you set the first elem to elem. So the stack looks like this :

> elem -> first -> next -> ... -> end;

and first id now the elem so basically you return to the first state :

> first -> next -> next -> ... -> end; (first is now the new elem you just added)

This schema may be helpful :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.next = first;
```

means previous first element should be next to your new element

```
first = elem;
```

means your new element becomes first